# Retrofit with XML - Element does not have a match in class

Tags: java, android, xml, retrofit2

I'm using `SimpleXmlConverterFactory` with Retrofit2. Below is the sample response i'm trying to parse:

```
<entries timestamp="1513178530.8394">
 <entry id="2" date="20170104">
   <fruits>
      <fruit type="apple" count="16"/>
      <fruit type="banana" count="12"/>
      <fruit type="cerry" count="5"/>
      <fruit type="lemon" count="2"/>
      <fruit type="orange" count="2"/>
      <fruit type="pear" count="0"/>
      <fruit type="pineapple" count="2"/>
   </fruits>
 </entry>
<entry id="21" date="20170306">
   <fruits>
      <fruit type="pear" count="1"/>
      <fruit type="orange" count="3"/>
      <fruit type="banana" count="1"/>
      <fruit type="cerry" count="1"/>
      <fruit type="apple" count="2"/>
   </fruits>
 </entry>
</entries>
```

Now i'm using the following class to parse:

```
@Root(name = "entries")
public class Entries {
    @Attribute(name = "timestamp")
    private String timestamp;
    @ElementList(name = "entry")
    private List<EntryLog> entry;
}

@Root(name = "entry")
class Entry {
    @Element(name = "fruits",required = false)
    private Fruits fruits;
}

@Root(name = "fruits")
class Fruits{
    @ElementList(name = "fruit")
    private List<FruitItem> fruit;
}

@Root(name = "fruit")
class Fruit {
    @Attribute(name = "type")
    private String type;
    @Attribute(name = "count")
    private int count;
}
```

I can't seem to get it work, the error says:

> org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'fruit' does
>   not have a match in class
>   com.github.irshulx.fruitdiary.apps.main.model.EntryLog at line -1

This error doesn't make sense. Because `fruit` does not belong in `EntryLog`.

Any helps is much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you need to annotate your `FruitItem` class with fruit root element?

Comment: tried it, still the same error

Comment: Why do you need a Fruits class? Your EntryLog has a `@ElementList(name = "fruits")` that's a `List<FruitItem>`

Comment: This is just a guess, try to make `FruitItem` as nested class of `EntryLog` or `Fruits`.

Comment: turns out needed to add `inline=true` for ElementList. Not sure how that fixes it, but it worked.
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 8):

This got it working:

```
@Root(name = "entries")
public class Entries {

    @Attribute(name = "timestamp")
    private String timestamp;

    @ElementList(name = "entry",inline = true)
    private List<EntryLog> entry;
}


@Root(name = "entry")
class EntryLog {

    @Attribute(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Attribute(name = "date")
    private String date;

    @Element(name = "fruits")
    private Fruits fruitItem;
}


@Root(name = "fruits")
class Fruits{

    @ElementList(name = "fruit",inline = true)
    private List<FruitItem> fruitItem;

}


@Root(name = "fruit")
class FruitItem {

    @Attribute(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @Attribute(name = "count")
    private int count;
}
```

had to add `inline = true` , although i'm not sure how that fixes the exception.

Comment: you can read more about inline here http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#inline